# 2 digit seven segment display

Tags: c, loops, avr, seven-segment-display

I am coding for a two digit seven segment display that counts up to 99, it is being called in a timer function that is fast enough so both digits are displayed at the same time with no flickering.
However the display is not outputting the correct numbers I want it to
for the case where the score is 0 to 9 it displays this on the right side of the SSD,
however once it hits 10 it displays 11 rather than 10, so it is displaying the digit of the tens on both the right and left sides. I am not sure what the error is in my code, such that I need to fix so it does display the correct number for the ones on the right hand side. I am getting the correct display for the tens digit on the left side though, so only issue is the right side.

```
// 0 = right digit; 1 = left digit.
volatile uint8_t seven_seg_cc = 0; 

    void seven_segment_display(){
        uint8_t score = get_score();
        seven_seg_cc = 1 ^ seven_seg_cc;

        if (score < 10){
            PORTC = seven_segment_display_one[score];
        }
        else if(score >= 10){
            if(seven_seg_cc == 0){
                //Display right dig
                PORTC = seven_segment_display_one[(score/10)%10];
            }else{
                //Display left dig
                PORTC = seven_segment_display_one[score/10];
            }
            PORTA = (seven_seg_cc << DDRA4);
        }
     }
```

Comment: The statement `seven_seg_cc = 1 ^ seven_seg_cc;` appears wrong. `seven_seg_cc` is not defined before.

Comment: Sorry seven_seg_cc is defined it is ```// Seven segment display digit being displayed.
// 0 = right digit; 1 = left digit.
volatile uint8_t seven_seg_cc = 0; ```

Comment: @John3136 we want to display both, so basically what it is doing is flipping the seven_seg_cc to be 0 and then to be 1 really quickly so both numbers are displayed at the same time

Comment: What's this strange stuff: `PORTA = (seven_seg_cc << DDRA4);`. You shift the value by whatever you have written to data direction. Or by a mask? How does that make any sense? And also, suppose the bit is set, 0x10 = 16. You then shift a `uint8_t` 16 bits. It's an 8 bit MCU so you have 16 bit int. The `seven_seg_cc` operand is promoted to int. You invoke undefined behavior. And how does it make sense to write this undefined result back to PORTA? Overall, your program suffers from sloppy signedness, where you use signed numbers all over.

Comment: @Lundin This code has been slightly altered to code already given to us, so I apologise for the "sloppy signedness'' of it cause that is how we have been taught and I have copied the example given to us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the modulus alone for the rightmost digit

```
        if(seven_seg_cc == 0){
            //Display right dig
            //PORTC = seven_segment_display_one[(score/10)%10];
            PORTC = seven_segment_display_one[score%10];
        }else{
            //Display left dig
            PORTC = seven_segment_display_one[score/10];
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much I have been trying to figure this out for a while now

Comment: You might also want to guard against a `score` value of `100` or more.